# how to use AndroidAnnotation for rest service to download a mp4 file

Tags: android, spring, rest, android-annotations

My question is I'm not sure how to user androidannotation rest api to download the files, below are my sample code"

I have created a restful service as below:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class BaseController {
   private String filePath = "web-inf/scheduler/downloadList.properties";
private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;

@RequestMapping(value = "/files", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void  getLogFile(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception{
    // get absolute path of the application

    ServletContext context = request.getSession().getServletContext();
    String appPath = context.getRealPath("");
    System.out.println("appPath = " + appPath);

    // construct the complete absolute path of the file
    String fullPath = appPath + filePath;
    File downloadFile = new File(fullPath);
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(downloadFile);

    // get MIME type of the file
    String mimeType = context.getMimeType(fullPath);
    if (mimeType == null) {
        // set to binary type if MIME mapping not found
        mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
    }
    System.out.println("MIME type: " + mimeType);

    // set content attributes for the response
    response.setContentType(mimeType);
    response.setContentLength((int) downloadFile.length());

    // set headers for the response
    String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
    String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"",
            downloadFile.getName());
    response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);

    // get output stream of the response
    OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int bytesRead = -1;

    // write bytes read from the input stream into the output stream
    while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }

    inputStream.close();
    outStream.close();

}

}
```

If I use Google chrome to browser the URL "http://[hostname]:8080/mnc-sms-endpoint/files" then it able to download the file.

Now I want to create an android app to get the file from this restful service.

Below is my android code: but it keep show me error and actually i'm new to androidannotation and spring-android.

```
@Rest(converters = { ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter.class })
public interface MainRestClient extends RestClientHeaders {
    // url variables are mapped to method parameter names.
    @Get("http://192.168.1.37:8080/mnc-sms-endpoint/files")
    @Accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
    byte[] getEvents();
}
```

and below is my android activiy:

```
@EActivity(R.layout.activity_main)
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
       @RestService
       MainRestClient mainRestClient;

 @AfterViews
    protected void init() {
       mainRestClient.getEvents();
```

}

```
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the error when your app calls the WS ?

Also you should remove `@Accept(...)` annotation, because your WS may return a different content-type than `application/octet-stream` (because of this line `String mimeType = context.getMimeType(fullPath);`)